# Core Data : What is an "entity" exactly?

Tags: core-data, entity

From what I learned in school many years ago, an entity is an actual object in a database. A recordset or a dataset.

This is how I remember it but I may be wrong.

But in many books I read an entity is not an object but the data model, like a class, for the object. When I am in the Core Data - Data Model Editor in Xcode and I click on "Add Entity" I don't add an object to the database but another data model.

So I am confused!

An entity, is it like an object, or like a class I can create objects from?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to become proficient in core data you should learn the associated vocabulary which admittedly might be counter-intuitive at first.

Let me stress that core data is **not** just a database wrapper but an object graph. Therefore, please take the equivalencies I give here with a grain of salt.

An **entity** would correspond to a table in a database.
An **attribute** would correspond to the particular fields in a table.
A **relationship** (to-one or to-many) would be the presence of a foreign key.
A **many-to-many relationship** would be a join table with two foreign keys.

One "record" in a database would be an **instance** of a certain entity. 
Note that it is common practice to model entities with corresponding classes which are subclasses of `NSManagedObject`. Thus instantiation works pretty much like with any other object, only that they are persisted in the database store.

Definitely spend some time on the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).